# How to use Regex to match a specific character pattern or format?

Tags: regex, master-data-services, mds

I am trying to create a Regex pattern that forces a string to match this format: A99.9.  (Alpha, Numeric, Numeric, Period, Numeric).  I am trying to build this into a business rule in Master Data Services. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://regex101.com/

Copy + Paste `/[A-Z][0-9]+\.[0-9]+/` make sure insensitive is selected; (so /[A-Z][0-9]+.[0-9]+/) how ever do you have any other formats you want to try? Is it really just A99.9, B88.8, C77.7 and so forth?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  It is case sensitive. I would like it to only accept UPPERCASE.  For right now, the only formats will be this one, the A99.9, B88.8, C77.7.  I can alter it in the future if needed, but right now I am trying to restrict users from entering anything other than that format into the MDS Excel add-on.

Comment: Ok makes sense, I've modified my answer; it'll strictly only accept A99.9, B88.8 and so forth - If it is really just to be A99.9 and not A99.987, you can remove the last plus at the end of the regex

Comment: Thanks!  I altered it slightly to this:  ^[A-Z][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]$ 
This forces the exact format to be matched with the way the business rules work within MDS.

Comment: You can also use an exact quantifier /^[A-Z][0-9]{2}\.[0-9]/ instead of + (which means one or more matches). In case you would ever have to match exactly 8 digits you would avoid having to copy [0-9] various times.